# How to set message instead of empty date in rdlc report c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, expression, rdlc

i am using RDLC reports, i have date column which shows date when date is available in Sql table but when not then it shows empty but that looks abnormal, i want to show message like 'Date Not Available' when empty etc, i tried expression in rdlc but it only formats date not anything else. Please help

```
=Format(Fields!DateReceived.Value, "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IsNothing`, like :

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DateReceived.Value),"Date Not Available",Format(Fields!DateReceived.Value, "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm"))
```